# Should I still use a process builder if it's easier to do something with a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, process-automation

When I have to choose between the process builder and flow, should I always choose flow? (because process builders won't be supported)

Or should I use a process builder when it's much easier to complete some task using the process builder instead of the flow?

Answer (score 4):

Using Process Builder is just leaving a headache for future you (or another admin). With the advancements in Flows, you can create anything in a Flow that you could in a PB in approximately the same amount of time; it just takes some time to get familiar with how Flows are built. I'd recommend taking a [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/build-flows-with-flow-builder) to get familiar with Flows, if you haven't already. If you've ever seen some of my past posts on Flows, you know that I used to be rather critical of them, but today they're far more friendly and intuitive than they were in the past.